# opengl texturing

Tags: c++, opengl

hi im trying to texture the floor of my level but when i call it the program compiles ok but the texture doesnt appear any help would be great

```
#include windows.h
#include gl\gl.h
#include gl\glut.h
#include stdlib.h
#include iostream>


#define ROAD 0


struct Image 
{
    unsigned long size_x;
    unsigned long size_y;
    char *data;
};

typedef struct Image Image;

const int textureCount = 1;

Image myTextureData[textureCount];
GLuint theTexture[textureCount];


char* textureFilenames[textureCount] = {"road.bmp"};



void init(void);
void display(void);
void keyboard(unsigned char, int, int);
void resize(int, int);
void drawcube(float, float, float, float, float, float, int);



int is_depth;




int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(600, 600);
    glutInitWindowPosition(40, 40);
    glutCreateWindow("3D World");
    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
    glutReshapeFunc(resize);  

    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}

void init(void)
{
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    is_depth = 1;
}

void display(void)
{

    if (is_depth)
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    else
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2f(0.0,0.0);
        glVertex3f(-75.0, 0.0, -400.0);
        glTexCoord2f(0.0,1.0);
        glVertex3f(-75.0, 0.0, 100.0);
        glTexCoord2f(1.0,1.0);
        glVertex3f(75.0, 0.0, 100.0);
        glTexCoord2f(1.0,1.0);
        glVertex3f(75.0, 0.0, -400.0);

        drawcube(-70,15,72,8,15,28,0);
        drawcube(-70,10,10,8,10,28,0);
        drawcube(-70,15,-45,8,15,18,0);
        drawcube(-70,15,-85,8,15,18,0);
        drawcube(-70,35,-125,8,35,12,0);
        drawcube(-70,9,-170,8,9,28,0);
        drawcube(-70,15,-220,8,15,18,0);
        drawcube(-70,15,-265,8,15,28,0);
        drawcube(-70,15,-330,8,15,28,0);
        drawcube(67,15,72,8,15,28,0);
        drawcube(67,10,10,8,10,28,0);
        drawcube(67,15,-45,8,15,18,0);
        drawcube(67,15,-85,8,15,18,0);
        drawcube(67,35,-125,8,35,12,0);
        drawcube(67,9,-170,8,9,28,0);
        drawcube(67,15,-220,8,15,18,0);
        drawcube(67,15,-265,8,15,28,0);
        drawcube(67,15,-330,8,15,28,0);
        drawcube(-33,18,-364,25,18,10,0);
        drawcube(25,28,-364,30,28,10,0);
        drawcube(25,28,90,30,28,10,0);
        drawcube(-33,18,90,25,18,10,0);
        drawcube(0,60,-125,18,60,22,0);
        drawcube(0,25,-225,8,25,28,0);
        drawcube(0,25,0,8,25,28,0);
        drawcube(-58,1,-135,4,0.5,215,0);
        drawcube(58,1,-135,4,0.5,215,0);
        drawcube(0,1,-345,60,0.5,4,0);
        drawcube(0,1,75,60,0.5,4,0);        



    glEnd();


    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    switch (key)
    {
    case 'a':
        glTranslatef(5.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        break;
    case 'd':
        glTranslatef(-5.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        break;
    case 'w':
        glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, 5.0);
        break;
    case 's':
        glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -5.0);
        break;
    }
    display();
}

void resize(int width, int height)
{
    if (height == 0) height = 1;

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    gluPerspective(45.0, width / height, 1.0, 400.0);
    glTranslatef(0.0, -5.0, -150.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

void drawcube(float xc, float yc, float zc, float x_offset, float y_offset, float z_offset, int color)
{

    switch(color)
    {
    case 1:
        glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0);
        break;
    case 2:
        glColor3f(0.0,1.0,0.0);
        break;
    case 3:
        glColor3f(0.0,0.0,1.0);
        break;
    }
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glVertex3f(xc - x_offset,yc - y_offset,zc - z_offset);
        glVertex3f(xc + x_offset,yc - y_offset,zc - z_offset);
        glVertex3f(xc + x_offset,yc + y_offset,zc - z_offset);
        glVertex3f(xc - x_offset,yc + y_offset,zc - z_offset);

        glVertex3f(xc + x_offset,yc + y_offset,zc - z_offset);
        glVertex3f(xc + x_offset,yc + y_offset,zc + z_offset);
        glVertex3f(xc + x_offset,yc - y_offset,zc + z_offset);
        glVertex3f(xc + x_offset,yc - y_offset,zc - z_offset);

        glVertex3f(xc - x_offset,yc - y_offset,zc + z_offset);
        glVertex3f(xc - x_offset,yc - y_offset,zc - z_offset);
        glVertex3f(xc - x_offset,yc + y_offset,zc - z_offset);
        glVertex3f(xc - x_offset,yc + y_offset,zc + z_offset);

        glVertex3f(xc + x_offset,yc + y_offset,zc - z_offset);
        glVertex3f(xc - x_offset,yc + y_offset,zc - z_offset);
        glVertex3f(xc - x_offset,yc + y_offset,zc + z_offset);
        glVertex3f(xc + x_offset,yc + y_offset,zc + z_offset);

        glVertex3f(xc - x_offset,yc - y_offset,zc + z_offset);
        glVertex3f(xc + x_offset,yc - y_offset,zc + z_offset);
        glVertex3f(xc + x_offset,yc - y_offset,zc - z_offset);
        glVertex3f(xc - x_offset,yc - y_offset,zc - z_offset);

        glVertex3f(xc + x_offset,yc + y_offset,zc + z_offset);
        glVertex3f(xc - x_offset,yc + y_offset,zc + z_offset);
        glVertex3f(xc - x_offset,yc - y_offset,zc + z_offset);
        glVertex3f(xc + x_offset,yc - y_offset,zc + z_offset);


    glEnd();
}

int imageLoader(const char *filename, Image *image) 
{
    FILE *file;

    unsigned long size;
    unsigned long i;
    unsigned short int planes;
    unsigned short int bpp;

    char temp;
    char finalName[80];

    glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0);

    strcpy(finalName, "" );
    strcat(finalName, filename);

    if ((file = fopen(finalName, "rb"))==NULL) 
    {
        printf("File Not Found : %s\n",finalName);
        return 0;
    }

    fseek(file, 18, SEEK_CUR);

    glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0);

    if ((i = fread(&image->size_x, 4, 1, file)) != 1) 
    {
        printf("Error reading width from %s.\n", finalName);
        return 0;
    }

    if ((i = fread(&image->size_y, 4, 1, file)) != 1) 
    {
        printf("Error reading height from %s.\n", finalName);
        return 0;
    }

    size = image->size_x * image->size_y * 3;

    if ((fread(&planes, 2, 1, file)) != 1) 
    {
        printf("Error reading planes from %s.\n", finalName);
        return 0;
    }

    if (planes != 1) 
    {
        printf("Planes from %s is not 1: %u\n", finalName, planes);
        return 0;
    }

    if ((i = fread(&bpp, 2, 1, file)) != 1) 
    {
        printf("Error reading bpp from %s.\n", finalName);
        return 0;
    }

    if (bpp != 24) 
    {
        printf("Bpp from %s is not 24: %u\n", finalName, bpp);
        return 0;
    }

    fseek(file, 24, SEEK_CUR);

    image->data = (char *) malloc(size);

    if (image->data == NULL) 
    {
        printf("Error allocating memory for color-corrected image data");
        return 0;
    }

    if ((i = fread(image->data, size, 1, file)) != 1) 
    {
        printf("Error reading image data from %s.\n", finalName);
        return 0;
    }

    for (i=0;i<size;i+=3) 
    {
        temp = image->data[i];
        image->data[i] = image->data[i+2];
        image->data[i+2] = temp;
    }
    return 1;
}

void textureLoader() 
{

    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

    for(int k=0; k < textureCount; k++) 
    {
        if(!imageLoader(textureFilenames[k], &myTextureData[k])) 
            exit(1);


        glGenTextures(1, &theTexture[k]);

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, theTexture[k]);


        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,GL_REPEAT);
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,GL_REPEAT);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);

        gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 3, myTextureData[k].size_x, myTextureData[k].size_y, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, myTextureData[k].data);
    }
}
```

Comment: might want to reformat that code

Comment: What does appear? and why are you drawing so many cubes?

Comment: How can it compile with the broken `#include`s?

Comment: you call drawcube within a glBegin(…)…glEnd() block. Drawcube itself opensanother glBegin(…)…glEnd() block. Those don't nest.

Answer (score 5):

You never call `textureLoader()`.

Or `glBindTexture()`, other than in `textureLoader()`, which you don't call.

Also, don't nest `glBegin()`s.

Comment: I also can't find glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)

Answer (score 0):

This may not directly answer your question, but I've found this [Intro to Modern OpenGL](http://duriansoftware.com/joe/An-intro-to-modern-OpenGL.-Table-of-Contents.html) *very* enlightening. In a simple way, it made a lot of the core concepts of the 3D math, graphics pipeline, and feeding data to OpenGL really gel with me.

If you read the first 5 posts I'm pretty sure you'll come away with a totally different perspective on how to tackle what you're trying to accomplish.